# vscode tailwind css intellisense not working

Tags: css, laravel, visual-studio-code, tailwind-css

I have a problem.
I'm learning laravel 8 and tailwind CSS.
and as title vscode tailwind CSS Intellisense not working.
My tailwind CSS version is 2.2.15. tailwind.config.js like the photo.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdOPm.png)
output no error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLIji.png)

so what can I do about this issue?

Comment: Have you added the Tailwind Css IntelliSense plugin to VSCode? Occasionally, mine will stop working so I have to disable / re-enable the plugin.

Comment: Yes，I try sublime and phpstorm ，sublime is work.  phpstorm doesn't.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 8):

[Tailwind CSS IntelliSense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss) extension doesn't work until you have a configuration file in your workspace, as its description clearly states!

You'll be fine even if you're just using the CDN, but you have to create a `tailwind.config.js` file in your project's root directory, containing the [defaults](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation) at least:

```js
module.exports = {
    content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
};
```

Also, and since you're working with Laravel, I guess you need to add Blade files to be recognized by the extension through this VSC setting (in `settings.json`):

```json
"tailwindCSS.includeLanguages": {
    "blade": "html",
},
```

Moreover, this extension can offer intellisense in CSS files. So such files need to be binded too:

```json
"files.associations": {
    "*.css": "tailwindcss",
},
```

*One final note: The `content` paths are what going to be processed by Tailwind's [JIT](https://tailwindcss.com/blog/just-in-time-the-next-generation-of-tailwind-css) engine; understanding it is **crucial**!*

Comment: I face the same problem with php file. After adding `tailwind.config.js` file in the root directory, problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

### Possible Solution

Disable a single VS Code Extension called:
"Bootstrap 4, Font awesome 4, Font Awesome 5 Free & Pro snippets"

### Evidence

Tailwind CSS IntelliSense was not working in my Angular project. I had installed Tailwind CSS using their instructions:

Click [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation)

**MY VERSIONS**

- VS Code: 1.62.3
- Tailwind CSS: 3.0.1
- Angular: 13.0.3

I disabled the extension, mentioned as my "Possible Solution" above, and Tailwind CSS IntelliSense worked instantly.

[Demo of Tailwinds CSS IntelliSense in my Angular project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjLUF.gif)

Answer (score 0):

i had same the issue while working on tailwind with laravel. 
unInstalling and reinstalling tailwind intellisense extension solved my problem.

also , dont forget to add the following in the  part of your blade file :

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it seems to be an issue with one of my extensions.

I needed to uninstall the "Emmet Live" extension and install the "Mithril Emmet" extension.

As some other answers have suggested, make sure you also put the following in your settings.json:

```
"tailwindCSS.emmetCompletions": true,
  "editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": true,
  "editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "strings": true
  },
"css.validate": false
```

Answer (score -1):

Using '' instead of "" might work.